# Which is the best practice for initializing a double in C++?

Tags: initialization, double, nan

I'm wandering which is the best practice to initialize a double. It is better to initialize it to 0.0 or NaN? And why?

Comment: Setting to `0.0` is completely different from `NaN`. The first indicates the value is `0.0` while the second indicates the values has not (yet) been set to a valid double.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best practice is just to initialize your variables. The value you choose depend of what you are doing: if you want to check the init of your variable, you choose a value which can not happen (or unique) in your algorithm (can be Nan, 0., -1., ...).